# Calculating Coords of a point Perpendicular to a Line, Calculating Coords of Third Point in Angle Given Two Points and Angle

Tags: geometry

[image: Diagrams]

I actually have two questions, I found the answer to the second and didn't update the diagram. I'm not actually sure if these are possible, they really stumped me.

**Question 1:**
Given point A and e, the angle of the line A is on relative to the x-axis where 0<=e<360 degrees, how do you calculate the coordinates of B? BA is perpendicular to A's line and 1 unit long.

SOLVED: I start by taking the unit vector from a parallel to the x-axis and then I rotate it 90 + e degrees.

**Question 2:**
I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211212/how-to-calculate-an-angle-from-three-points) approach. If anyone has any better suggestions, please let me know.

SOLVED: I find the dot product of the vector from step 1 and the normalized vector AC.

**Question 3:**
This one should be pretty self-explanatory from the diagram. I need to find the coordinates of C given A, B, the angle of BAC and the distance between A and C.

SOLVED: I rotate BA e degrees and then change the magnitude to d.

If anyone spots problems with my solutions, please comment.

Comment: What's with all the math questions recently?  Some prof must have given out a stumper of a homework assignment.

Comment: Or perhaps it's just because math is a big part of certain areas of programming?

Comment: Belongs on geometryoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy if you understand vectors.  Learn about how 2D vectors work and you'll have it.  Is that the course you're taking?

1. Take the unit vector from e to A, knowing that a unit vector has length 1.  Assume l1 = xi + yj.  The perpendicular vector has components that are the reverse of l1 with one sign changed.  In this case, l2 = -yi + xj.
2. Take the vector l2 that you got from the first problem and transform it as follows:

cx = -cos(t)y - sin(t)x
cy = +sin(t)y + cos(t)x

where t is the rotation angle in radians.

I'll leave the third one for you.  Read about 2D vectors and transformations.

Comment: e isn't a point on the line, it's the angle of the line relative to the x-axis. The only point that I know on that line is A.

Comment: Yes, I know.  Like I said, you need to learn about 2D vectors and transformations.