# Get x,y point from angle and radius

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to get a specific point with specified angle and distance(Radius) from center point of my base UIView. I found this question [How to calculate a point with an given center, angle and radius?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912779/how-to-calculate-a-point-with-an-given-center-angle-and-radius) but this doesn't give me correct point. I'm using below code to find the point,

Basically i need to find the x,y point from 100px distance and 90 degrees(clock wise) from center point of my base view.

```
int angle = 90 * M_PI / 180;//need to find the point of 90 degrees
int distance = 100;
int line_end_x = 160 + cos(angle)*distance;//160 is my center x
int line_end_y = 274 + sin(angle)*distance;//274 is my center y
myView.center = CGPointMake(line_end_x, line_end_y);
```

Above code gives me below output,

Red box is "myView" with (20px x 20px)

[image]

May be someone can tell me whats wrong i'm doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt that you want your angle to be expressed as an `int`. 
Your angle is Pi/2 which is 1.57.

Maybe try `float angle = 90 * M_PI / 180;`

Comment: If anyone curious to know, 0 degrees starts from 3 in the clock dial, Mistakenly i started from 12 in my image.

Comment: Yup, the convention is that the origin of angles is the `x` axis, *ie*. the horizontal one ;-)