# problem with angles

Tags: java

Hi
this a part of my code :
I have a list which its size is three and I consider that 2 last items are in one line (p and q) I need to get the angle between the first item of this list and these two points (p,q)

```
    private Point partition(List<Point> list, Point p, Point q) {



    double x1 = p.getX();
    double x2 = q.getX();
    double y1 = p.getY();
    double y2 = q.getY();
    double pQ = Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size()-2; i++) {
        double pointX = list.get(i).getX();
        double pointY = list.get(i).getY();
        double pointQ = Math.sqrt((x2 - pointX) * (x2 - pointX) + (y2 - pointY) * (y2 - pointY));
        double pointP = Math.sqrt((pointX - x1) * (pointX - x1) + (pointY - y1) * (pointY - y1));
        double angle = Math.acos((pQ * pQ - pointP * pointP - pointQ * pointQ) /(- 2 * pointP * pointQ));
        System.out.println(angle);


    }
```

but instead of printing an angle for the first item it will print :(first item is not in the line of two last items).

```
1.6288442476732894
```

those points that print  this result are :

```
[X :143.0  Y: 217.0, X :93.0  Y: 163.0, X :193.0  Y: 165.0]
```

please help me thanks.

EDITED : really it makes me confused .in such a way it will print this value ,sorry all !!!

Comment: Why `i < list.size()-2;`? I would expect `i < list.size()-1;`.

Comment: @Matt: there are no functions in the code above that take radian arguments. acos takes a number between -1 and 1 and returns a value in radians.

Comment: I use i<list.size()-2 because those two last points are in one line and I do not need test them.

Comment: Can you show the point values that generate that output?

Comment: Why do people continue to help somebody with a 33% accept rating???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arccos is bad, you need a parenthesis and a `-` :

```
 arccos((pQ^2 - pointP^2 - pointQ^2)/(-2 * pointP * pointQ))
```

see [How to calculate an angle from three points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211212/how-to-calculate-an-angle-from-three-points)

Comment: I have changed it but still doesn't work well.it will print value more than one

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` is a special double value meaning "not a number". It is generated as a result of some "bad" calculations:

- dividing 0 by 0
- dividing infinity by infinity (any combination of positive and negative)
- multiplying 0 by infinity, either positive and negative, and vice-versa
- adding negative and positive infinity
- subtracting negative from positive infinity, and vice-versa
- the square root of a negative number
- the logarithm of a negative number
- the inverse sine or cosine of a number not between -1 and 1
- any calculation involving one or more NaN values.

Check the result of the argument to the inverse cosine function (`acos`). I bet it is off the valid range.

Comment: You mean `1.5707963267948966` is the value of `(pQ * pQ - pointP * pointP - pointQ * pointQ) / 2 * pointP * pointQ` ?

Comment: See RC's answer. He knows why you're trying to calculate the inverse cosine of a number out of the [-1,1] range.