# Using Python to find distance and angle of surrounding data points in 3D. Finding straight lines

Tags: python, scipy, ipython

I am using Ipython Notebook. I am working on a project where I need to look at about 100 data points in 3D space and figure out the distance between each and the angle from one another. I want to see correlations of the data points and ultimately see if there is any structure to the data (a straight line hidden somewhere). I have looked into clustering techniques and hough transforms, but they seem not to give me the result I need. Any ideas are much appreciated.. thanks!

Comment: Just do a linear regression on the data points. `scipy` is a good package for this.

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue of determining the pairwise distance between three dimensional points, you can use `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist()`. This will generate n(n-1)/2 distances for n points. For the second issue finding the angle between points, that's trickier. It seems so tricky that I don't even really want to think about it; however, to that end, you can use `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine()`, which will determine the cosine distance between two vectors.

Have you looked at scikits? I've found them very helpful in my work. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/

Comment: It might be useful to combine the vector-pair technique with the angle formula contained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1211243/401828

Answer (score 0):

The distance is best found using `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist()` as mentioned in cjohnson318's answer.  For a small array of points 'a' defined as:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[4,2,-2],[3,-1,2]])
```

The distance euclidean distance 'D' between the points can be found as:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
D = squareform(pdist(a))
```

In 3d polar notation, you would need 2 angles to define the direction from one point to another.  It seems like a Cartesian unit vector giving the direction would likely serve your purpose just as well.  These can be found as:

```
(a-a[:,np.newaxis,:]) / D[...,np.newaxis]
```

This will include NaN's in the diagonal elements, as there is no vector from a point to itself.  If necessary, these can be changed to zeros using `np.nan_to_num`

If you actually do need the angles, you could get them by applying `np.arctan` to the components of the unit vector.