# how to display the joint angle on the main window

Tags: c#, sdk, kinect, angle

I am new to C# programming and I am following the Kinect For Windows SDK from Channel9msdn and Microsoft Kinect Toolkit examples. My question is how do I obtain and display the joint angles for each joint?

Also, how do I display the coordinates of the joints?

I want to have these displayed when I am running the skeletal tracking.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: There is no automatic calculation for joint angle.  You will need to calculate it yourself and display it.

Comment: what is the calculation/equation and how do I display it with the skeletal tracking running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick internet search...

[How to calculate an angle from three points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211212/how-to-calculate-an-angle-from-three-points)

For displaying the text, you can either draw it directly to the display canvas or create one (or more) TextBlocks that you update the value of.  I would probably suggest the TextBlocks, simply because they would be easier to work with.

Information on how to work with TextBlocks can be found in the MSDN development documentation, and all around.