# libGDX - How can I draw polygon as a line (Miter join type)?

Tags: java, math, libgdx, drawing

If I have known vertices (RED) like this image:

[image]

- [Drawing Lines is Hard](https://mattdesl.svbtle.com/drawing-lines-is-hard)
- [Line Joins](ftp://ftp.sgi.com/opengl/contrib/blythe/advanced99/notes/node281.html)

**How** can I determine these below unknown vertices from above known vertices which join lines as a miter joining with each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, look at this [Q/A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849784/calculate-miter-points-of-stroked-vectors-in-cartesian-plane). 
Your task is the same, only a bit simpler, since line thickness is the same for all segments.[image]

Basically, you need to calculate coordinates of **D** point, when
coordinates of **A**, **B**, **C** and line thickness **d** are known.

1) Calculate angle α, using [Law of Cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines), like here
[How to calculate an angle from three points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211212/how-to-calculate-an-angle-from-three-points)

2) Then you can find length **L** of vectors u and v:

```
L =|u| =|v| = d / sin α;
```

3) Calculate vector components for vectors **u** and **v**:

```
ux = L * (Ax – Bx) / |AB|;
uy = L * (Ay – By) / |AB|;
```

|AB| - length of vector **AB**, can easily be found from coordinates of points **A** and **B**.

```
vx = L * (Cx – Bx) / |BC|;
vy = L * (Cy – By) / |BC|;
```

4) Finally find coordinates of point D:

```
Dx = Bx + ux + vx;
Dy = By + uy + vy;
```

5) Do that for all points of you line.

Comment: That s it Answer which looking for. Thank you so much.