# How to find curve corner points using JTS or NTS?

Tags: java, c#, .net, jts

I have a curve (say JTS edge):

[image]

How to find all curve direction change points that surpasses given angle using [JTS (Java)](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/) or [NTS (C#)](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite):

[image]

Comment: As some pointers in the right direction... for each polygon, you can take the exterior ring and then start iterating through computing the angles as you go.

Comment: As far as computing the angles at each point [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211212/how-to-calculate-an-angle-from-three-points) might help.  You don't say if you care about internal vs. external angles, so I'll leave that for you to figure out...

Comment: The question isn't unclear. It could use some context though. What is the overarching goal?

Answer (score 1):

I did some research and made some tests on JTS, and the best way I found is:

- Create polygons and use the function `union`
- Then iterate over the Coordinates, and create a sub-array on each "hard angle" (negative scalar product) and when the sum of angle reaches 180 (don't take the last angle to avoid non-function issues)
- Then I change the base to an orthonormal base with `x(firstElemOfSubArray, lastElemOfSubArray)` by computing the base-changing matrix, and I then recompute the sub-array in a new coordinate system
- I then create a function using `org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.interpolation.SplineInterpolator` to interpolate the function of the course, and then I get the derivative and search the extrema (don't take elements with an ordinate that is too low). With its absysse you can find which point is an inflexion point
- So the point you search for are first elements of each sub array, and its inflections points (if there are any)

Comment: that's a whole project i need to finish this then push it some where