How to calculate the angle from a point to midpoint of a line?
I want to calculate the angle formed by a line segment from p1 to the midpoit of the line connecting p2 and p3, and the line formed by p2 and p3. I used code as below, but the result seems not correct, does anyone help me?
def calculateAngle(point1, point2, point3):
    lon1, lat1 = point1
    lon2, lat2 = point2
    lon3, lat3 = point3
    latCenter = (lat2 + lat3) / 2
    lonCenter = (lon2 + lon3) / 2
    xV1 = latCenter - lat1
    yV1 = lonCenter - lon1
    xV2 = lat3 - lat1
    yV2 = lon3 - lon1
    dotProduct = xV1 * xV2 + yV1 * yV2
    magnitudeV1 = sqrt(xV1 ** 2 + yV1 ** 2)
    magnitudeV2 = sqrt(xV2 ** 2 + yV2 ** 2)

    if magnitudeV1 == 0 or magnitudeV2 == 0:
        return 0
    
    cosTheta = dotProduct / (magnitudeV1 * magnitudeV2)
    cosTheta = max(min(cosTheta, 1), -1)
    theta = acos(cosTheta)
    angleInDegrees = degrees(theta)
    return angleInDegrees, theta



What are the inputs?  Make a [mcve] and show the expected (correct) output vs. the actual output. “Seems not correct” is not helpful.

for p1(100.3,40.96666666666667), p2(110.4, 13.983333333333333), p3(110.96666666666667, 13.966666666666667)), the angle about 68°, but calculation result is 0.516°.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1211243/212869 might help

This question is similar to: Calculating angles between line segments (Python) with math.atan2. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

[Edit] the question to make a [mcve].  New information should be in the question, not in comments, to make the question stand on its own.

Great! Thanks alot!, answer me, pls.

IMHO that's not a programming but basic geometry knowledge question.

Your V1 and V2 vectors are wrong.  You have:
    xV1 = latCenter - lat1
    yV1 = lonCenter - lon1
    xV2 = lat3 - lat1
    yV2 = lon3 - lon1

What you want is:
    xV1 = lon1 - lonCenter
    yV1 = lat1 - latCenter
    xV2 = lon3 - lonCenter
    yV2 = lat3 - latCenter


If you look at your diagram, it should be clear.  Both vectors run from the midpoint to the points point1 and point3.  And longitude is X, latitude is Y.  Again, this is correct in the diagram but reversed in the original V1 and V2 assignments.
Note that you could alternatively use:
    xV1 = lon1 - lonCenter
    yV1 = lat1 - latCenter
    xV2 = lon3 - lon2
    yV2 = lat3 - lat2

This effectively doubles the magnitude of V2, which will cancel out when later dividing by its magnitude.
